# Using D3 to read data into associative arrays

Tags: javascript, csv, associative-array, d3.js

I'm trying to loop through a set of values and read in separate files (using d3.js) into javascript associate arrays , but the argument is not being passed properly into the internal function.  For example:

```
var reg_list = [];
var all_region_data = [];
reg_list[0]="region1";
reg_list[1]="region2";

// Function to read in data from all regions in reg_list. 
function read_regional_data(region_list) {
    for (i=0;i<reg_list.length;i++) {
        region = region_list[i];
        console.log("Read data for " + region) // THIS RETURNS REGION1, THEN              
            // REGION2
        all_region_data[region]=new Array()
        d3.csv('filepath' + region + '.csv', function(csv){
                    console.log('reading for ' + region) // THIS RETURNS REGION2 TWICE
            csv.map(function(x) {
                all_region_data[region].push(x.cause);
            })
        console.log("Finished Reading Data for " + region)
        })
    }
}
```

When I execute this, I iterate through both regions in the loop, but region1 is never passed into the d3.csv function. This may have something to do with the d3.csv being run asynchronously?  Any thoughts on how to avoid or improve this are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion instead of the loop to iterate over the regions --

```
var reg_list = [],
    all_region_data = [];
reg_list[0]="region1";
reg_list[1]="region2";

function read_regional_data(i) {
    var region = reg_list[i];
    console.log("Read data for " + region);
    all_region_data[region]=new Array();
    d3.csv('filepath' + region + '.csv', function(csv){
        console.log('reading for ' + region);
        csv.map(function(x) {
            all_region_data[region].push(x.cause);
        });
        console.log("Finished Reading Data for " + region);
        if(i < reg_list.length) {
            read_regional_data(i+1);
        }
    });
}
read_regional_data(0);
```